# CKeditor strips empty anchor tag when no name attribute is provided

Tags: ckeditor

I have some anchor tags that are in a WYSISWYG text editor. They are empty anchor tags with just id and title attributes. They look something like this:

```
<a id="test" title="test"></a>
```

They were put into the editor using just a basic text editor and then saved. When they are imported into the WYSISWYG text editor and then saved, those anchor tags go away. I know this isn't the correct way to use an anchor tag and I know I could manually go into the anchor tag and add a name attribute to fix this problem (something like this will fix the problem:

```
<a id="test" name="test" title="test"></a>
```

My problem is that these anchor tags already occur in probably over 100 places and for me to find out where all these places are would take way too long. Is there a setting in the config that I can set so that it will ignore these empty anchor tags? Based on the documentation, it seems that $removeEmpty field should do the trick but I have had no luck. I have tried many different versions of it:

```
"CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['a'] = 0;", "CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['a'] = false;", "CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.a = 0;", "CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.a = false;", etc.
```

I have also tried using the protectedSource config setting but that will just ignore anchor tags in the WYSIWYG text editor and then it looks like there are no anchor tags on the page. Anybody have some insight? There has got to be a way to override the settings and allow empty anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding `config.allowedContent = true;` to your config.js file. But that turns off the advanced content filter.

A better way is to configure `extraAllowedContent` to specify that you want to allow anchor tags without any attribute restrictions, like so:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[*]';
```

More information:

- [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) - specifications for this configuration
- [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) – how to write allowed content rules, which are used in several places including config.allowedContent, config.disallowedContent, and config.extraAllowedContent